# Is there anything to spend extra currency (eg. Hertareum, Shield) on after clearing out their respective shops?

Tags: honkai-star-rail

[image]

This is the spare Hertareum and Shield I have currently in-game. I have fully bought out both the shops on the Herta Space Station and Jarilo-VI.   Is there anything to spend extra currency (eg. Hertareum, Shield) on after clearing out their respective shops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra currencies can be used to purchase [credits](https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Credit).

[image]

This change was added in the [Version 1.1 "Galactic Roaming" update](https://web.archive.org/web/20230623114026/https://hsr.hoyoverse.com/en-us/news/111793):

> Adds credit items to the World Shop. These credit items will be available for exchange after all limited items are exchanged. There is no exchange limit for credit items.